# C++ - ofstream overloaded operator '<<' is ambiguous?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I am having trouble solving this error.

Use of overloaded operator '<<' is ambiguous (with operand types 'std::ofstream' (aka 'basic_ofstream') and 'std::string' (aka 'basic_string<char, char_traits, allocator>'))

My first assumption was because of the similar ostream operator, but no luck.

Any help is much appreciated.

maintest.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

#include "player.h"

int main() {

//#########################################################################
    // TEST - Overloading Stream Operators
    //**************************************************************
        // Test ostream & istream
    /*std::cout << "\n---ISTREAM/OSTREAM TEST---\n";
    Player playerS1;
    std::cin >> playerS1;
    std::cout << "Test output: ";
    std::cout << playerS1;*/

    //**************************************************************
        // Test ofstream
    std::cout << "\n---OFSTREAM TEST---\n";
    Player playerS2;
    int playerScoreS2(66);
    std::string playerNameS2("Tanner");
    
    playerS2.SetName(playerNameS2);
    playerS2.SetScore(playerScoreS2);

    std::ofstream outFile;
    outFile.open("testFile");

    if(!outFile.is_open()) {
        std::cout << "Could not open file." << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "File opened." << std::endl;
    }

    outFile << playerS2;

    std::cout << "File closed." << std::endl;
    outFile.close();

    
    // Return here!!!
    return 0;
}
```

player.h

```
#ifndef PLAYER_H // MACRO guard
#define PLAYER_H

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

class Player {
    public:
        Player(); // Default constructor
        Player(const int &score);
        Player(const std::string &name);
        Player(const std::string &name, const int &score);

        // Output functions
        std::string toString() const;
        std::string toFileString() const;

        friend std::ostream&  operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Player& line);
        friend std::ofstream& operator<<(std::ofstream& outFS, const Player& line);
        friend std::istream&  operator>>(std::istream& in, Player& line);
        friend std::ifstream& operator>>(std::ifstream& inFS, Player& line);

    private:
        std::string name;
        int score;
};
```

player.cpp

```
/*********************
OTHER MEMBER FUNCTIONS
*********************/
std::string Player::toString() const {
    // What is the format????
    // Using comma delimited for now.
    return name + ',' + std::to_string(score);
}

std::string Player::toFileString() const {
    return name + ',' + std::to_string(score);
}

/****************************
INPUT/OUTPUT STREAM OPERATORS
****************************/

/*std::ostream&  operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Player& line) {
    out << line.toString() << std::endl;
    return out;
}

std::istream&  operator>>(std::istream& in, Player& line) {
    std::cout << "\nEnter Name: ";
    in >> line.name;
    std::cout << "Enter Score: ";
    in >> line.score;
    return in;
}*/

/*std::ifstream& operator>>(std::ifstream& inFS, Player& line) {
    inFS >> line.name >> line.score;
    return inFS;
}*/

std::ofstream& operator<<(std::ofstream& outFS, const Player& line) {
    outFS << line.toFileString() << std::endl;
    return outFS;
}
```

My assumption, based on the assignment, was that the ostream and ofstream operators were essentially the same but using two different functions outputing in different formats. (They currently output the same format).

Any advice?

Comment: Can you explain why you believe an `ofstream` overload is needed, in addition to the `ostream` one? What problem will that solve?

Comment: Based on my limited knowledge of operator overloading and the assignment instructions I assume it is requested because the ostream function handles user output and the ofstream handles file output. The program demands different formatting depending on the output. Although the .toString() and .toFileString() functions currently return the same format, this will change.

Comment: An overall redesign is highly recommended, to find some different approach to do this task. As is, this will be just non-stop pain, anguish, and tears. Since `Player` has a non-explicit constructor, both overloads appear to participate in the overload resolution for a `std::string`, and neither one is preferrable to the other.

Comment: In general, prefer to mark single-argument constructors as `explicit`.

Comment: A minimal reproducible code example here: https://godbolt.org/z/ds8T6qEPs -- indeed, making the string constructor explicit resolves the issue. But I agree it's not a great design. Better to do something like wrap a Player object in a PlayerPresentation class or similar, which handles the I/O for a particular type. And don't define these operators directly on Player.

Comment: Many thanks! It took some long hours and internal screaming, but I managed to piece it together. I appreciate the help.